# Using Google Dataflow template, is there simple way to whitelist all tables in a Database instead of passing a comma separated list of all the tables

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, debezium

Using this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates for CDC for MySQL and publishing to google Pub/Sub topic.
In the properties file, there is a provision for `whitelistedTables=` where you have to give a comma separate list of all the tables you want to monitor for change.

Is there any straightforward way to whitelist an entire database and in turn all tables in it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the whitelisetedTables parameter does not allow for whitelisting all tables for a given database. However, Dataflow templates are customizable. You can download the code from Github then re-upload your modified version to GCS. Then, you can run your new templated job that allows for this feature. See this prior question: [How to Customize GCP Dataflow template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64097374/how-to-customize-gcp-dataflow-template). The code for the Dataflow templates live here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates.